# Separating multiple search criteria with a comma

Tags: vba, ms-access, search

I am using an Access form to search a table using different textboxes, i.e. Title, Author, Date etc.

Right now I use this code to perform the search, and update a subform with the results:

```
Private Sub sFindData(strTitle As String, dtmDate As String, strAuthor As String)

    On Error Go to E_Handle
    Dim strSQL As String
    If Len(strTitle) > 0 Then
        strSQL = strSQL & " AND Title LIKE '*" & strTitle & "*' "
    End If
    If (IsDate(dtmDate)) Then
        strSQL = strSQL & " AND DocumentDate=" & Format(Me!txtDate, "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#")
    End If
    If Len(strAuthor) > 0 Then
        strSQL = strSQL & " AND Author LIKE '*" & strAuthor & "*' "
    End If
    If Left(strSQL, 4) = " AND" Then
    strSQL = " WHERE " & Mid(strSQL, 5)
    End If
    strSQL = "SELECT Title, DocumentDate, Author FROM tblDocument" & strSQL
    Me!sSubTable.Form.RecordSource = strSQL
sExit:
    On Error Resume Next
    Exit Sub
E_Handle:
    MsgBox Err.Description & VbCrLf & VbCrLf & Err.Source & VbCrLf & VbCrLf & "sFindData", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Error: " & Err.Number
```

And I use this code to call sFindData through textboxes on the form:

```
Private Sub txtTitle_Change()
    Call sFindData(Nz(Me!txtTitle.Text, ""), Nz(Me!txtDate, #12/31/2099#), Nz(Me!txtAuthor, "")
End Sub
```

I have a Change Sub for every textbox in the main form, each bound to its own field through the same code shown above.

My problem is, I sometimes need to search multiple criteria of the same type (two different document titles for example), and I want to be able to do it in one field if possible, i.e. separate the two criteria with a comma (Title#1, Title#2) and have the code search both of these criteria and show the results on the subform

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is non-trivial, and without any attempted code goes beyond what SO is for. You would need to detect the presence of a comma in the text boxes, split into an array, loop the array building up a SQL string using `OR`, take care with bracketing of the different parts of the `WHERE` statement.

Comment: The `.Text` property is a string. No need to wrap it with the `Nz()` function as it will never be null.

Comment: I see, in that case, is there any alternative way for me to approach this? Maybe have one textbox for the search, with a button that adds another textbox if the user wants to search 2 (or more) different parameters that might be in the same field? Ideally I want to be able to let the user filter the search results in a variety of ways, as the final product will contain hundreds of files and a single parameter search might not cut it.

Comment: It makes more sense  in this case to have a button. The `Change()` event is usually to apply a filter on a single field.

Comment: Your code is going to break horribly if someone searches for a title with an apostrophe in it. Don’t use `REPLACE`, use query parameters!

Comment: The problem with having a button, though, is that I need the search form to display/update results on the subform with every keystroke. Is there no feasible way of pulling this off?